# How to proxy on Svelte-kit in dev mode

Tags: svelte, vite, sveltekit

I am trying to redirect for local development my requests to `/api/**` to my backend server.

So a request to `http://localhost:3000/api/upload` goes to `http://localhost:8080/api/upload`.

I cannot find any `svelte.config.js` configuration, to get this to work for dev. Also [`svelte-kit dev`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/cli#svelte-kit-dev) does not provide this configuration (or I cannot find it).

Does anyone know how to do so in svelte-kit?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the Vite config (`vite.config.js`) you can configure this via [`server.proxy`](https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-proxy), so it should be something like:

```js
const config = {
    // ...
    server: {
        proxy: {
            '/api': 'http://localhost:8080',
        },
    },
};
```

Comment: In 2022 it's moved to `vite.config.js`, as you can see in svelte.kit [docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/project-structure).

Comment: @gyurielf the answer says exactly this, so your comment adds nothing.

Comment: @Coreus: That is because I updated it accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the Typescript version (for those that need that).

**vite.config.ts** (usually found at root)

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte'

// Docs: https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [svelte()],
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': 'http://localhost:8080'
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Do not edit the answer based whether you use single or double quotes. People's preferences are different and such edits are thus as biased as the answer.

Comment: I only see javascript