# Deploy Azure Static Web App with Sveltekit and Fastapi

Tags: azure, azure-functions, sveltekit, azure-static-web-app

I am trying to deploy Sveltekit to Azure Static Web Apps with a Fastapi backend.  I think I am close, but not sure if what I want to do is even possible.  I went through a Microsoft article about [creating a react app with an api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/how-to/with-web-app/static-web-app-with-swa-cli/introduction?source=recommendations) and followed the steps outlined in the [svelte-adapter-azure-swa](https://github.com/geoffrich/svelte-adapter-azure-swa).  I am using the fastapi function from [another Microsoft learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/fastapi-on-azure-functions/azure-functions-python-create-fastapi-app/), which I have successfully deployed on its own.

The Sveltekit function `sk_render` and the fastapi `WrapperFunction` are located in an api directory and are present within the staticwebapp project.

[image: Current Static App setup].

My app is deployed and renders, however I receive a 404 when trying to fetch from the fastapi function.

### routes/+page.svelte

```
<script>
   
    import { onMount } from "svelte";
    
    let userName = ""
    onMount(async function () {
      const response = await fetch('api/hello/Jon');
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
      userName = data.name
    });
</script>
<h1>Welcome to SvelteKit {userName}</h1>
<p>Visit <a href="https://kit.svelte.dev">kit.svelte.dev</a> to read the documentation</p>
```

[image: error message]

I am not sure if there is some type of configuration I am missing in the host.json or function.json.

### host.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
  },
  "extensions": 
  {
    "http": 
    {
        "routePrefix": "api"
    }
  }
}
```

### function.json

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ],
      "route": "{*route}"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks

Comment: i'm exactly in the same situation. did you find your solution in the mean time?

Comment: @pietz From what I gather this is not possible.  The functions all run under the same runtime environment so python cannot run in the node runtime.  The best way to go (that I see) is to create a separate function for fastapi.

Comment: I made it work to use Sveltekit in SPA mode hosted on Azure SWA with Azure Functions in Python as an API. However, the moment I try to use FastAPI within Functions instead, I don't get any response from my endpoints. I've tried different combinations of adding and removing "/api" from fastapi routes and function.json - Nothing worked.

Comment: I just realized our problems are different sorry. I simply have problems seetings up fastapi with a SPA SWA webapp

Comment: @pietz I think your problem is having a proxy.  I was able to do a proxy in dev mode by configuring the vite.config [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72753203/4296857), but couldn't figure it out in production.  So instead I just set up some environment variables for my dev and prod endpoints.  So instead of "/api" I have "ENV_VAR_TO_FASTAPI_FUNCTION/endpoint".  I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Interestingly, I did come back to this and finding myself in the same position. This time for real :) I'm able to create a FastAPI backend in a separate function app but within a SWA, it doesn't work. Have you found a solution to this after all?